# the count function will not work properly

Tags: python

```
i = input("enter") 
count = 0
if i in"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
    count = count+1
if i in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
    count = count+1
if i in "1234567890":
    count = count+1
if i in "@!£%^&*()_+{}:?><":
    count = count+1



print(count,I)
```

when I input say, a or A or 1 or ! just by themselves as a single character count will = to 1. however, when I input more than one such as 'aA', or 'AA' count will = to 0. why is this?

Comment: Simple, because "aA" or "AA" is in neither of the strings/char-arrays

Comment: `in string` looks for a substring. So if you input `aA`, it's looking for that exact substring somewhere in the alphabet.

Comment: I think this question could use an explanation of what the program is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'aA' in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` is only true if the exact sequence `aA` appears somewhere in `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, not if any of the characters can be found.

You can use the `any()` function to test each character separately.

```
if any(c in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" for c in i):
    count += 1
```